# Как получить public_token/access_token в plaid при помощи python

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь следовать документации Plaid [отсюда](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-python#examples) и не могу понять, откуда мне взять public_token. Далее в примере написано:

```
# the public token is received from Plaid Link
response = client.Item.public_token.exchange(public_token)
access_token = response['access_token']
```

Но где мне взять этот public_token?
Запустив сервер Flask все получилось, но я хочу решение без поднятия сервера, скажем в Jupiter Notebook

Вроде как его получить можно сделав GET запрос. Но куда его делать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350395/how-does-one-retrieve-the-public-token-for-plaid-api-in-python Ссылка на подобный вопрос, но ответа там так и не дано

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](http://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#tokens):

Public_token (который возвращается в вашем обратном вызове `Link onSuccess()`) должен быть передан на ваш сервер, который заменит его на access_token.

public_tokens - токены одноразового использования, срок действия которых истекает через 30 минут. При необходимости вы можете сгенерировать новые public_tokens через конечную точку [/item/public_token/create](https://plaid.com/docs/#create-public-token).

Соответственно если у Вас имеется access_token:

```
# create a public_token for use with Plaid Link's update mode
create_response = client.Item.public_token.create(access_token)

# use the generated public_token to initialize Plaid Link in update
# mode for a user's Item so that they can provide updated
# credentials or MFA information
public_token = response['public_token']
```

Access_token используется для доступа к данным продукта для элемента. Это должно храниться надежно, и никогда в коде на стороне клиента. Это используется для выполнения аутентифицированных запросов к Plaid API для пользователя. По умолчанию access_tokens не имеют срока действия, хотя вы можете вращать их; если он попадает в состояние ошибки, access_token снова будет работать, если ошибка элемента устранена. Каждый access_token уникален для определенного Предмета и не может использоваться для доступа к другим Предметам.

**Примечание**: access_token и public_token не применимы для продукта payment_initiation. Подробнее смотрите в документации по токену оплаты.

Comment: А если у меня нет ни того, ни другого? У меня есть только client_id, secret, public_key. Собственно чтобы получить access_token мне нужен public_token. Вы же говорите что для получения public_token мне нужен access_token. Как выйти из этого порочного круга?

Comment: "вы можете сгенерировать новые public_tokens через конечную точку POST /item/public_token/create" Как мне сделать это если у меня не поднят сервер?

Comment: автор написал, что через Flask всё получилось. значит у него на руках имеется access_token с помощью которого он может получать public_token без участия клиента

Comment: а по поводу конечной точки, в моём ответе есть пример кода из оф.документации

Comment: может я не правильно выразился. Задача в следующем: при использовании Flask все отлично: после ввода client_id, secret, public_key все работает. Но это при наличии Frontend и клиентской отправки данных с обработкой на локальном сервере. Я хочу обойти клиентскую часть и генерировать токены на основе имеющихся данных